# vbtab in reporting services 2008 expression

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, vbscript, tabs

i am trying to use tabs in reporting service 2008  expression on a particular textbox.
i have tried using three tabs (& vbTab & vbTab & vbTab &) between field name and value for two fields.

```
=iif(Trim(Fields!Field1.Value) <>"", "FVE1:" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab &  Fields!Field1.Value & VbCrLf,"") & iif(Trim(Fields!Field2.Value) <>"", "RV:" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & Fields!Field2.Value,"" )
```

what i am trying to aceive is some thing like this

```
FEV1:   3.29
RV:     0.51
```

But i am unable to achieve this insted it get like below

```
FEV1:   3.29
RV:   0.51
```

any help will be much appeiciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If tabs do not work, try right-aligning with non-breaking spaces `Chr(160)`:

*(Line-wrapped for legibility)*

```
= Iif(
  Trim(Fields!Field1.Value) <> "", 
  "FVE1:" & Fields!Field1.Value.ToString().PadLeft(5, Chr(160)) & VbNewLine, 
  ""
) 
& Iif(
  Trim(Fields!Field2.Value) <> "", 
  "RV:" & Fields!Field1.Value.ToString().PadLeft(5, Chr(160)),
  ""
)
```

Comment: i get the error: 'String' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression.

Comment: @jk1844 `String` is a function in VBScript, and that's what you tagged your question with. Could it be that you're not using VBScript, but VB.NET?

Comment: yes sorry its vb.net. any ideas how to go about with this? thanks

Comment: @jk1844 In VB.NET you can use [`String.PadLeft()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft.aspx). See modified answer. PS: Please correct the tags in your question.

Comment: @jk1844 Is there a way you can display the source code of the report? What if you add spaces manually? Are they lost?

Comment: @jk1844 If manual spaces are not lost, then those created by `PadLeft()` will not be lost either. Everything else does not make sense.